# Large numbers become negative in haskell

Tags: haskell

```
(product (take 9 [1000,999..])) `div` (product (map (\j-> product [1..j]) (map (\j->length(j)) (group [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]))))
```

The above code is of the form  X `div` Y, with `X=product (take 9 [1000,999..])` & `Y=(product (map (\j-> product [1..j]) (map (\j->length(j)) (group [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]))))`

If I copy and paste the code in ghci, it gives me `-12740133310672` as an answer,
but if I count `X & Y` individually, I get `964541486381834014456320000 & 362880`, then dividing them gives me `2658017764500203964000` as an answer.

I think this incoherence might be because the number is too large, but since the computer can calculate X and Y correctly individually, how come it can't also divide them combined?

Comment: it's just the `length` in there - this will constraint the result to `Int` but you really want `Integer` - use `(\j -> fromIntegral $ length j)` which is just `fromIntegral . length` instead

Comment: as an alternative you could use [`genericLength`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:genericLength) too

Comment: btw: the last parth is really strange as the last part is just `[9]`, etc.

Comment: @Carsten, `genericLength` should never be recommended.

Comment: You can use `Integer` to make use of arbitrary precision type which is limited by your system memory.

Comment: @dfeuer ... well I only mentioned it ^^

Comment: @Carsten So in this code it becomes "Integer divide Int"(), which gives the absurd result?

Comment: @CYC, no, the arguments to `quot` are forced (by `quot`'s type) to have the same type. The type of the second argument is determined by the type of `length` to be `Int`, so the type of the first argument must be as well. When you write the numerator separately, it *defaults* to `Integer`.

Comment: @dfeuer So this means X is forced from "Integer"(It's too long, so can only be an Integer) to be "Int"(determined by length), which makes it crash?

Comment: @Carsten I copied and pasted `Y` wrong, I had edited it so it's in the correct form now.

Comment: @CYC, no, not really, but I really should be asleep now rather than trying to explain type class polymorphism. Someone will probably explain it properly before I wake up.

Comment: @dfeuer What's wrong with genericLength?

Comment: @amalloy, the way it's written it's efficient for lazy naturals with addition defined a certain way, but it's inefficient for anything else. This is partially patched up with rewrite rules for `Int` and `Integer`, but I don't think anything else. So unless you're doing something really weird, `fromIntegral . length` is better. `fromIntegral` itself is problematic, but not big-O problematic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Prelude Data.List> let x = product $ take 9 [1000,999..]

Prelude Data.List> x
964541486381834014456320000
Prelude Data.List> :t x
x :: (Enum a, Num a) => a
```

Observe that `x` has the type of a *generic number*: you calculated it with just operations that work *for any* number type. When you evaluate such a number in GHCi, it defaults to the “safest” concrete type, which is `Integer`, an arbitrary-precision type which has no problem with big numbers. However, you can enforce the calculation to be done with any other numerical type:

```
Prelude Data.List> x :: Integer
964541486381834014456320000
Prelude Data.List> x :: Float
9.645414e26
Prelude Data.List> x :: Double
9.645414863818342e26
Prelude Data.List> x :: Int
-4623139575776374784
```

The floating point versions are inaccurate but still close, whereas `Int` (a machine-size fixed precision number) simply overflows and gives complete bogus.

Normally this won't bother you, because huge calculations are by default done with the safe `Integer` type.

That is, unless something else prevents it.

```
Prelude Data.List> let y = product (map (\j-> product [1..j]) $ map length (group [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]))

Prelude Data.List> y
362880
Prelude Data.List> :t y
y :: Int
```

Unlike `x`, the type of `y` is already concrete: it *must* be `Int`, because that's the result type of [`length`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:length). (The rationale being: a list that's so big that you couldn't measure its length with an `Int` would not be able to fit in memory anyway.)

Now, [`div`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:div), like most numeric functions in Haskell, requires that the arguments and result have all the same type. For this reason, `` x`div`y `` will as a whole be calculated as `Int` instead of `Integer`, including `x`. And as we've seen, calculating `x` as `Int` gives bogus.

OTOH, if you use `362880` as a literal, then this isn't connected to `length`. It's just a generic number, like `x`, hence GHCi will again default to safe `Integer`, i.e. you get

```
Prelude Data.List> x `div` 362880
2658017764500203964000
```

The same result can be achieved if you just allow *conversion* of `y`:

```
Prelude Data.List> x `div` fromIntegral y
2658017764500203964000
```

Comment: Uhh - I see, he really just pasted the result, the literal value. Now everything makes sense! Great answer!

Answer (score 0):

Using Integer instead of Int helps:

```
let r :: Integer ; r =  (product (take 9 [1000,999..])) `div` (product (map (\j-> product [1..j]) (map (\j->fromIntegral $ length(j)) (group [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]))))
```

gets me: 2658017764500203964000

I don't fully understood your code, but I assume if you calculate them individually you get smaller intermediate results - so Int won't overflow.

So yes - the incoherence is because of large numbers (Int is limited in it's width, so it will just overflow (negative numbers). If you operate with such large numbers you should probably use Integer, which has unlimited width.

Comment: Haskell won't calculate X and Y out first, and then divide? Since Haskell can calculate them individually, how come it can't calculate X divide Y which gives a smaller number?

Comment: No it does that. Your individual calculations don't work for me - I'll have to check later, gota run.